# ejs Template data is not inserting in to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to insert data from ejs template to mongodb using mongoose.
page is redirecting successfully after clicking on submit button and my data is also showing in url but that is not inserting in to MongoDB Collection.

**app.js**

```
 var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
   var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   var mongodb = require('mongoDB');

   var routes = require('./routes/index');
   var users = require('./routes/users');

   var app = express();

   // view engine setup
   app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

   // database connection
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/company');
   var mySchema=new mongoose.Schema({
   name:String,
   email:String
   });
   var user=mongoose.model('emp', mySchema);


   // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
   //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
   app.use(logger('dev'));
   app.use(bodyParser.json());
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
   app.use(cookieParser());
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

   app.use('/', routes);
   app.use('/users', users);

   // catch 404 and forward to error handler
   app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   var err = new Error('Not Found');
   err.status = 404;
   next(err);
   });

   // error handlers

  // development error handler
  // will print stacktrace
  if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
  }

  // production error handler
  // no stacktraces leaked to user
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
  });


  module.exports = app;
```

**Index.ejs**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
     <title><%= title %></title>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>

  <div style="margin:0 auto ; width:50%; padding:20px">
    <form action="/users">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
      <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
      <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
    <button>submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**index.js**

```
 var express = require('express');
   var router = express.Router();

  /* GET home page. */
  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  });
  router.post('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  new user({
   name:req.body.name,
   email:req.body.email

  }).save(function(err, docs){
   if(err)
   {
     res.json(err);
   }
   else
   {
     res.send('success Inserted !');
   }
  });
  });

   module.exports = router;
```

Comment: See `new user(..)`. You are not importing your `user` model, nor showing any of the code where this is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly You Have to define form method Post because you define route type post .  And in your index.js file you are not initialize  user object and data connection so you have to initialize user and data connection in index.js file which you define in app.js file. Remove user initialization and data connection  From app.js file.

Code:

**index.ejs**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
     <title><%= title %></title>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>

  <div style="margin:0 auto ; width:50%; padding:20px">
    <form action="/users" method="post">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
      <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
      <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />
    <button>submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**index.js**

```
  var express = require('express');
  var router = express.Router();
   // database connection
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/company');
   var mySchema=new mongoose.Schema({
   name:String,
   email:String
   });
   var user=mongoose.model('emp', mySchema);
      /* GET home page. */
      router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
      });
      router.post('/users', function(req, res, next) {
      new user({
       name:req.body.name,
       email:req.body.email

      }).save(function(err, docs){
       if(err)
       {
         res.json(err);
       }
       else
       {
         res.send('success Inserted !');
       }
      });
      });

       module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thank u . Its working fine... Problem is solved, now Data is inserting successfully  in Collection